# How to set up Apache server via an FTP account

Tags: apache-2.2, django, mod-python

I have developed a web application in Django and would like to go online
i have an FTP access to the hosting server
I am a beginner to "setting up a website"
i would like to know how to install apache on that server and have my application working and how to test for the python interpreter i.e mod_python installed so that i can export my django application

Kindly provide detailed info as i am newbie, any links or tutorials would help a lot

Thanks in advance

Comment: If FTP is enough to set up the website then your hosting company will have documentation on what needs to be done.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot setup apache via FTP. If you have been provided only with FTP access them probably your hosting company has already setup Apache and the FTP access is provided only to upload data to the server. Check with your provider.

Comment: ok...
so then how do i go about setting up my django application so that it works with the apache on the server via FTP